# File writer fails to write to existing json?

Tags: java, filewriter

File writer fails to write to existing json ?

I definitely get the value but write buffer is null during the whose process.

How to fix this issue ? No error or exception is caught.

I have tried using different types of Writer too.

```
     String path = resourceHelper.getFilePath(DOCUMENT_PATH2);
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(path));
        writer.write(gson.toJson(documentToSave));
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
```

OR

```
Files.write(Paths.get(path), new Gson().toJson(documentToSave).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Comment: Is the value of `path` a relative file name?

Comment: no its absolute

Comment: *File writer fails to write to existing json ?* If you're expecting to *append* to existing json, it's not going to work as your `FileWriter` is not opened in append mode

Comment: I added but issue wasnt resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    String path = resourceHelper.getFilePath(DOCUMENT_PATH2);
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(path));
    String json = gson.toJson(documentToSave);
    System.out.println(“json: ” + json);
    writer.write(json, 0, json.size());
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
```

Comment: It did work, but when I open the file it is not seen what could be a reason. While in debug log I could see the change reflecting

Comment: Does the file timestamp indicate that the file was touched at the time the program was run? Also, use new FileWriter(path, true)